# Re-link a mask to its layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

**How to a re-link a layer mask to its layer?**

I have unlinked a mask from its layer so I can feely move the image affected separate from the mask. Now, I would like to re-link them so I may move both in tandem. I do not want to Control+Z or "ADD to layer" because this removes the ability to edit the mask layer.

*I thought it would be as simple as a right-click or layer option, but all of these are non-selectable (grayed out - see attached).*

[[image: notice the tool tip saying link layer - the mouse hover displays a no option symbol not shown on screen capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left click between the layer and the mask.

[image: Linking Mask]

Comment: Just realized this -.- But thank for a prompt and correct answer! the GIF you provided leaves nothing to imagination.